# Perl regex to find a string that is not matched

Tags: regex, apache, perl, mod-rewrite

I need to find a string that doesn't match a given regex in perl.  For example: If the string is:

```
%3C9ba91570d204095439e82b74ab4d74b0%3E%3Cma%3E%3C5975%3E
```

I need to fetch 'ma', that is a string within '%3C' and '%3E' sub-strings. So any string within these two sub-strings should be matched.  I mean, if 'ma' is not there, it may be any other string ('am') like in this example:

```
 %3C9ba91570d204095439e82b74ab4d74b0%3E%3Cam%3E%3C5975%3E
```

It is to be used in RewriteRule in apache so that this fetched value is stored in an environment variable.

I tried this, but it doesn't give what I desire:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (%3C.*?%3E%3C.*?)(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=FetchedValue:%2]
```

Any help to solve this will be great...!

Comment: What if you try: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} %3C(.*?)%3E` and `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=FetchedValue:%1]`?

Comment: No, it gives 9ba91570d204095439e82b74ab4d74b0, but I need 'ma' sub-string.

Comment: What about `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (ma|am)%3C(.*?)%3E` and `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=FetchedValue:%2]`

Comment: No, this type of regex will not work, since (ma|am) is unknown.  It might by any other string also. I need to match any string within '%3C' and '%3E', and that too at its second occurrence.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} %3C.*?%3E%3C(.*?)%3E` and
`RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=FetchedValue:%1]`

Comment: yes, the regex from 'horcrux' works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really sure that it will always be the second string between %3C and %3E there is multiple possibility like:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} %3C.*?%3E.*?%3C(.*?)%3E
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=FetchedValue:%1]`

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex is fine. On the other hand, you have an input / specification problem. Consider the following `grep` command, based on your regex:

```
echo '%3C9ba91570d204095439e82b74ab4d74b0%3E%3Cma%3E%3C5975%3E' | grep -Po '%3C.*?%3E'
```

- `grep -P` enables perl syntax. I skipped the trailing `.*` parts, otherwise it's the same regex as yours.
- `grep -o` will keep the matches only

So, we got three matches, the second one is what you want:

```
$ echo '%3C9ba91570d204095439e82b74ab4d74b0%3E%3Cma%3E%3C5975%3E' | grep -Po '%3C.*?%3E'
%3C9ba91570d204095439e82b74ab4d74b0%3E
%3Cma%3E
%3C5975%3E
```

So, this raises two questions:

1. Is this a valid cookie value
2. How do you want to differentiate between the `ma` match and the other two?